# the `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined" MongooseError

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to begin mongoDB and mongoose challenges on freecodecamp and want to answer through a deployed web app from heroku. I have successfully completed the first challenged via my heroku app that connects mongoose to database. But when I try to run the code locally it returns with this error.

```
throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +

MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined".
```

Also, the app doesn't complete challenge two which is to create a model in which the code is written correctly as I found the answer online to make sure that wasn't the problem. I think it is because of this error and I have no idea how to fix it. Please help me .

This is myApp.js

```
require("dotenv").config();
const mongoose = require("mongoose"); // Need to require mongoose
//** 1) Install and set up mongoose. (connected it to heroku as well.)
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
  // The MONGO_URI string is in sample.env. Be sure to change <password> to the user's actual password for mongoose to connect to the database
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
```

here is my sample.env file (yes it is saved in the root part with package.json and myApp.js)

```
MONGO_URI="mongodb+srv://password2:rhyme@cluster0.77bp9.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

Comment: Have you named the .env file as sample.env, If so dotenv will not read it I suppose, Try renaming it to simply .env and give it a try?

Comment: It is amazing how something so trivial was holding it back. That seemed to do the trick. Thank you Roshan!!

Answer (score 1):

You need not to enclose MongoURI in quotes to identify it as string . You should remove quoutes around it.

```
MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv://password2:rhyme@cluster0.77bp9.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Also make sure :

```
    const dotenv = require('dotenv');

    dotenv.config({ path: './sample.env' });
```